# To manullay calculate the total duration of jmeter testplan from the Logfile

Tags: jmeter

I want to manually calculate the Duration of jmeter testplan from the csv Logfile.I was following the calculation of last timestamp-first timestamp and it looks correct if am running for 1 thread group.For more than 1 threadgroup the samplers will be repeating and I think it should not be the right way to calculate the duration.I tried using transaction controller thinking that the corresponding timestamp will give me the duration of all contained samples but got confused when I saw multiple transaction controller entry in the Log file for more than one threadgroup. I am newcomer in the performance testing and in the jmeter.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter provides variable which holds test start timestamp, it is `${TESTSTART.MS}`
2. You could use [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) which is designed to run post-test actions. Under tearDown Thread Group you can use [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) to print test duration to *jmeter.log* file as follows:

   ```
   long start = Long.parseLong(vars.get("TESTSTART.MS"));
   long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
   log.info("Test duration: " + (end - start) / 1000 + " seconds");
   ```

By the end of the test you should see something like:

```
2015/06/17 22:20:15 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Test duration: 300 seconds
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more Beanshell scripting tips and tricks.

If you have only result file, another option is open .jtl results file with Excel or Google Sheets or equivalent, sort timestamp column (usually the first one), subtract first cell/first row value from the first sell/last row value - this way you'll get test duration in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and I think the sorting of the timestamp column and then the difference calculation should do the trick.Will work out on it.
meantime is it possible to find the duration from the transaction controller log entry?I found it to be the aggregate of the child samples so if am having one such parent, that parent sample's timestamp should give me the duration of the whole test.[suppose am including all my samples as the child of a parent transaction controller].Please correct me if am wrong here.